# Adding image to TTabItem in Firemonkey

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, delphi-10.3-rio

I have a TTabControl with a single tab that displays an image on the tab when a field in the tab has contents.  I've assigned an ImageList to the TTabControl.  When I add additional TTabItems to the TTabControl, I am unable to assign an ImageIndex later in the code.  Here is how I'm adding the new tab:

```
procedure TfrmAddEditItem.LoadCustomFields;
var
  NewTab: TTabItem;
begin
...
  NewTab := TTabItem.Create(tabPictures);
  NewTab.Name := 'tab2';
  NewTab.Text := FieldByName('FieldName').AsString;
  NewTab.Visible := True;
  NewTab.Enabled := True;
  NewTab.Tag := tabPictures.TabCount + 1;
  NewTab.Parent := tabPictures;
...
end;
```

But in another function in the form, when I try to set the image on the tab I get an Access violation exception:

```
procedure TfrmAddEditItem.LoadDataFields;
var
  FormFieldName: string;
  DBFieldName: string;
begin
...
  FormFieldName := 'tab' + FieldByName('FieldID').AsString;
  DBFieldName := 'Field' + FieldByName('FieldID').AsString;
  Tab := TTabItem(Self.FindComponent(FormFieldName));
  if FieldByName(DBFieldName).IsNull then
    Tab.ImageIndex := -1
  else
    Tab.ImageIndex := 0;
...
end;
```

How can I set the ImageIndex value programatically on a TTabItem I added within the code?  (Note that there are other events where I will also want to adjust the image based on the value in a database field.)

Comment: Hard to say, as you have not provided compilable code, or even code including all type definitions and variable declarations. Also, when you get an error message, always indicate on which line it was reported and include the complete message in your question. The error message includes addresses, offsets and other information that usually helps a trained eye to evaluate the cause. In `procedure LoadDataFields` you assign variable `Tab` a `TTAbItem` but you don't check if `FindComponent()` was successful. If it wasn't, `Tab` would be `nil` and you would get the AV you mention.

Comment: Debugging your code would have revealed the error in practically no time.

Comment: Thanks for the tips in posting - this was my first time.  In LoadDataFields I use FindComponent successfully for a number of other fields, so I didn't think to check if it was successful with the Tab (this is a port from a Delphi 2009 application).  Turns out it was nil, but if I used FindComponent on the parent TTabControl it did find the component.